# What to use instead of reshape when the number of observations within one day are not the same?

Tags: matlab, reshape

I am just starting to learn Matlab and I would appreciate very much if you could help me...

I am stuck with calculating the returns between some hours and for each day..
For some data was going ok the following method:

```
(now the price is between that hours)
n=length(price);
% The number if days 
%(79 is the number of observations within one day)
ndays = n/79;
price_d = reshape(price,79,ndays);
%I take returns for each day
returns_d = log(price_d(2:79,:))- log(price_d(1:78,:));
```

However now I have another data where the number of observations are not anymore the same for each day..So in one day I have 79 in another 30,75 observations within a day. Therefore I CANNOT use anymore RESHAPE..:(

How should I do in order to have sorted the observations(prices) according to each day? So to have similar thing as before: row with the prices and column with prices corresponding to each day..

So I have a nx1(n=935039) vector of the data like this: 734142 734142 734142 734142 734142 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143..

Then a vector with prices:1115.80000000000 1115.40000000000 1116 1116 1115.80000000000 1115.70000000000 1115.70000000000 1115.40000000000 1115.60000000000 1115.60000000000 1115.70000000000 1115.60000000000 1115.80000000000 1115.80000000000 1115.70000000000 correpondig to each date...

And a vector with time in seconds:0 300 600 900 1200 1500 1800 2100 2400 2700 3000 3300 3600 3900 ...

There is no way to split them either in one matrix with I don't know how many rows(which are gonna be the prices for each day) but I know the number of columns 1260(which are the days I have).. Or if not just to make 1260 vectors(nx1) with the prices for each day.

In Ox will be something like this(my coordinator 4 phd told me,but he doesn't use matlab):for(i = 1; i <= sizeof(vdates); i = i+1) daily_file = selectifr([bid,ask], dates .== vdates[i]); if empty continue save daily_file contract_name + "_" + sprint(vdates[i]) + ".mat"; HOwever I cannot find the opossite function of ''selectifr'' from Ox to Matlab..

I have the future index on S&P for my 5minutes intraday data. So I prefer to have either in one matrix the days(1260)columns with prices(rows)(like I have them when using reshape)..Or to have 1260 nx1 vector with prices correspondig to each day.. After I will have to look where the volume is changing so I am passing to another contract(Rolloverdates)..Can you help me to split them in days,or individual vectors with prices for each day?

..I don't have a nx1260 vector...I was just saying that my unique(dates)=1260

Comment: Just calculate returns on the whole time series, and NaN out the overnight returns, i.e. those corresponding to the change in the day. To find when the day changes, if you have the serial date, you can `datevec()` it and do a `find(diff(dayvector))`.

Comment: Sorry but if you have a `A = n x 1260` matrix, why not simply `A(2:end,:)./A(1:end-1,:)-1`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cell array that contains vectors of different lengths, one for each day. Calculating something for each day can then be done using `cellfun` or `arrayfun`.

```
>> measurements = {[1,2,3],[10,11],[14,15,16,17]};
>> avg_per_day = cellfun(@mean, measurements)
avg_per_day =
    2.0000   10.5000   15.5000
```

Comment: Sorry if maybe is a stupid comment..I have 935039 rows of the prices ( and if I am calculating the unique(dates) I get 1260 days)..So I have to mache those rows with prices to this days..so in the first day may be 79rows(prices),the 2nd day 40..

Comment: That is my problem:how do I put them in a cell array?

Comment: How do I say take me for each day the  coressponding prices and put them in a cell array?:d

Comment: Hard to say if you do not give any example of your data. But have a look at `mat2cell`.

Comment: @MarinelaFinta Please, incorporate the comments into your main post to make it copy-pastable into Matlab and delete the comments afterwards.

Comment: @BasSwinckels I figure it out how to split my data into cells according with days..How do I calculate for all the cells for instance the log and difference(sum them)..I've tryed:log_day=cellfun(@log,price) but is not working..